# Counterexample for 2-22 of Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

If $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $D_2f = 0$, show that $f$ is independent of the second variable.

I was thinking of ways to show this, when I came across what I think might be a counterexample.

Possible counterexample: Consider the function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $$f(x,y) =
\begin{cases} 
x & \text{ if $y \geq 0$} \\
x^2 & \text{ if $y < 0$.} \\
\end{cases}$$

Then $D_2f = 0$, but $f(x,1) = x, f(x,-1) = x^2 \Rightarrow f(x,1) \neq f(x,-1)$, showing that $f$ is not independent of the second variable. Am I missing something here? It seems like the above theorem should work, i.e. that $f$ is independent of the second variable, but the counterexample seems convincing enough that I'm afraid I might have overlooked something.

An idea that just came to be is that $\lim_{y\rightarrow 0^-} \frac{f(x_0,y)-f(x_0,0)}{y-0}=\infty$, which does not equal to $\lim_{y\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{f(x_0,y)-f(x_0,0)}{y-0} = 0$. Does it sound right?

Comment: Also, can I directly argue that $\lim_{y\rightarrow b} \frac{f(x_0,y)-f(x_0,b)}{y-b} = 0$ implies that $f(x_0,y)-f(x_0,b) = 0$ for some $b \in \mathbb{R}$ and some fixed $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$, or should I justify the step? I was wondering if there's a more detailed way, since I technically can't multiply $y-b$ on both sides.

Comment: Notice that in your counterexample the derivative of $f$ with respect to $y$ does not exist in $(x_0, 0)$

Comment: Yor función seems not to have the corresponding partial derivative at points of the form $(x,0)$

Comment: You may try to use the mean value theorem on the second component by comparing $f(x,a)$ and $f(x,b)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**hint:** the above statement can be proved using the mean value theorem with respect to $y$. As I said in the comments, your counterexample is not valid, since the exercise assumes that $D_2f$ exists everywhere. Your function fails to be differentiable with respect to $y$ in every point $(x_0, 0)$.

Comment: Got it, I see what I'm missing now. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This is not a counterexample, because your function $f$ is not always a continuous function of $y$ for constant $x$, and therefore $D_2 f$ does not exist everywhere. For example, consider
$$f(2,1)=2$$
and
$$f(2-\epsilon, 1)=4-2\epsilon$$
So that
$$4=\lim_{x\to 2^-} f(x,1)\ne \lim_{x\to2^+} f(x,1)=2$$

Comment: Well, it is not continuous, but that does not mean $D_2f$ does not exist.

Comment: @Dude Good point, it’s worth stating explicitly that $f$ is discontinuous as a function of $y$ when $x=2$ (say).

Comment: Thanks for the example!